# How to Deploy multiple versions from one Project

Tags: c#, iis, msdeploy

I have an .Net 4.0 solution, and i use Visual Studio 2010.

in that soulution there is an startup project. I deploy the Project with the Webdeployment method, onto the IIS, the client can then go to the publish.html of the corresponding website, and install the application.

My problem starts when i try to release two different versions of that prooduct and try to install both on the same machine, then the installer thinks that the application is already installed. (after i install the first version of the product, the installer then complains that there already is an app with this name but i changed the product name)

How can i publish two different versions of my project, on two seperate websites? and have them install on the same machine at the same time?

Comment: each install need there own product guid. check in the property tab when you select the install project. if you only change the update guid one will replace the other. if you change the product one windows will see both as different software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this problem, as the commenter Franck pointed out, there has to be some sort of distinction between those apps.

So i made just different keys for the different Variations i wanted to deploy:

Rightclick on the Startup project -> Properties -> Tab: Signning-> here one can create certificates for as many Variatons as one pleases, be sure to save the different certificates for later deployments!

when deploying a certain variation i then simply swap the file, and then msdeploy "thinks" it manages different apps.